# Using Nasa's API bit confused by the URL

Tags: ajax, url

I'm intressted in getting photos from Nasa's Mars rovers that can be found here
https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#MarsPhotos

particularly the MISSION MANIFEST that is said to be stored under /manifests/rover_name

So i assumed this would work

https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifest/curiosity/status&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Sadly this just gives me "No API Key supplied" error.

Does anyone have experince with this and know what the propper URL is for getting the manifest data?

Comment: Looks like you just need to obtain an api key from them, if you're using that exact url you posted, the response is correct because "DEMO_KEY" is not valid.  This works and it's just the key listed on their site.  https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo

Comment: i have a propper key, the link you gave are for the APOD part of there API. I'm intressted in getting the manifest as describe by the link above

Comment: Remove the '/status&' from the end of your URL and just replace it with a '?', This URL seems to work, https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifests/curiosity?&api_key=DEMO_KEY  documentation here... https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#MarsPhotos

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the right endpoint at:

```
https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifests/Curiosity/?api_key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the url: for first parameter you must prepend "?", which means "beginning of parameters"; for the others you use "&", which is a separator.

Example:

```
http://www.apisite.com/folder/folder/?query   - Full url

http://www.apisite.com - Server

/folder/folder/ - Service

?query - parameters

query:  param1=xxx&param2=yyy&param3=zzz
```